# Adjusting Single Appendix title

Tags: numbering, appendices

I'm writing my thesis in `report` document class with several packages including

```
     \usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
     \usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
```

To create the **only** appendix in my document I type

```
     \begin{appendices}
     \chapter{}
     \section{Some title here}
     Some text here!
     \end{appendices}
```

This works fine and produces "Appendix A" in the table of contents. However, since it is the only appendix, I'd rather not have an "A" in front of "Appendix". To suppress this I used

```
     \setcounter{chapter}{-1}
```

which does the job, **but** makes the numbering of sections (and subsections) in the appendix "ugly" with ".1", ".1.1", etc. Does anyone know a better way of doing this?

PS I've read the answers to the two questions on Appendices here
http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/faq/author-faq
but still am not able to fix the issue.

Comment: Could you bring us a full MWE? Otherwise is very hard to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide local redefinitions for `\thechapter`, `\thesection`, `\thesubsection`, `\thefigure` and `\thetable`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{appendices}
\renewcommand\thechapter{}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand\thetable{\arabic{table}}
\chapter{}
\section{A test section}
Some text here
\subsection{A test subsection}
Some text here
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting ToC:

[image]

An image of the Appendix in the document body:

[image]

Notice that this can produce ambiguity, since you will have two different objects with the same numbering (the first chapter of the document and the first section in the appendix are both numbered "1", for example). To avoid this, you could number the sections alphabetically or using Roman numerals:

```
\renewcommand\thechapter{}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand\thetable{\arabic{table}}
```

or

```
\renewcommand\thechapter{}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand\thetable{\arabic{table}}
```

Comment: This is very helpful Gozalo. I also agree with you about the ambiguity in numbering, but my university guidelines require using "Appendix" rather than "Appendix A" when there is only one appendix and I'm not really sure how I should do the numbering of sections in this case. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The best solution that comes to my mind is to (easily) modify your code to produce numbering like "i.1" however, I don't want to do the numbering quite arbitrarily in case some "standard" or at least better solution exists. Thanks so much!

Comment: @EPS Yes, That's what I'd suggest; changing the numbering schema for sections to use alphabetic characters or Roman numerals; please see my updated answer.