# How to display just the word APPENDIX in appendix title?

Tags: appendices

Similar questions have been asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262585/adjusting-single-appendix-title).. but I cant seem to make the solution work for me. What I'm trying to do is just display the word APPENDIX, which is centred. Then after that, I would like to include some text. However, in the example below, it keeps displaying APPENDIX A.

How do I eliminate the 'A' from the appendix title?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}

\title{appendixTest}
\author{Mr. Anderson}
\date{July 2021}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    
    \section{Introduction}
    There is no spoon!
    
    \begin{appendices}
        \renewcommand{\appendixname}{APPENDIX}
        \centering\section{}
        
        \textbf{Title Here!}
        \newline
        Some appendix text here!!!!
    \end{appendices}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't it help to put an asterix for the section? So, `\centering\section*{}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw that my comment did not help haha. But this does:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}

\title{appendixTest}
\author{Mr. Anderson}
\date{July 2021}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    
    \section{Introduction}
    There is no spoon!
    

    \begin{appendices}
        \centering\section*{APPENDIX}
        
        \textbf{Title Here!}
        \newline
        Some appendix text here!!!!
    \end{appendices}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: That solved the problem. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for the `article` class but would be slightly different for the `book` or other classes that defined `\chapter`.

This MWE replaces your `appendices` environment by a simple `\appendix` as it appears that you might have only a single appendix.

```
% appendixprob.tex  SE 604719

\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass{report}  %%% produces different appendices layout
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[title]%  %% title option maybe irrelevant
  {appendix}

\title{appendixTest}
\author{Mr. Anderson}
\date{July 2021}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    
    \section{Introduction}
    There is no spoon!
  
\appendix   %% just one so don't need appendices environment
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{APPENDIX}
%\appendixpage %% in article class prodes a \part title (left justified)
\begin{center}  %% center APPENDIX
\appendixpagename
\end{center}
       
        \textbf{Title Here!}
        \newline
        Some appendix text here!!!!
%    \end{appendices}
 
\end{document}
```

However, this version does use the `appendices` environment.

```
% appendixprob2.tex  SE 604719

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}

\title{appendixTest}
\author{Mr. Anderson}
\date{July 2021}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    
    \section{Introduction}
    There is no spoon!
  
    \begin{appendices}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{APPENDIX}
%\appendixpage %% in article class prodes a \part title (left justified)
\begin{center}  %% center APPENDIX
\appendixpagename
\end{center}
       
        \textbf{Title Here!}
        \newline
        Some appendix text here!!!!
    \end{appendices}
 
\end{document}
```

Processing either version produces the same result.

[image]