Set chapter number to blank
I am working in overleaf.
I have Chapter headings as follows in the preamble:
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filcenter}{\mbox{}\xrfill[0.4ex]{3pt}
[rulecolor]\textsc{\LARGE\enspace\chaptername~\thechapter}\enspace\xrfill[0.4ex]{3pt}[rulecolor]\mbox{}}{0.3ex} {{\color{rulecolor}\titlerule[1pt]}\vskip3ex\huge\bfseries}[\medskip{\color{rulecolor}\titlerule[1pt]}]

It works fine. However, in
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\appendix
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Appendix}
\chapter{Something to append}
\end{document}

I get
----Chapter 1-----

Chapter 1

-------Appendix  A------

Something to append

I would like to suppress the A, that is, get
-------Appendix------

Something to append

If I replace \chapter{Something to append} with \chapter*{Something to append} I get

Something to append,

that is, it kills Appendix as well as the A
Is there some way to a new chapter command, say \appchapter, and reproduce the \titleformat command with appropriate modification or is there a better solution?

Could you have a look at these two questions marked as a code sample
mark your inline code? This might help to see which parts of your post are part of your document and which parts are part of your question. In its current form it is a bit hard to understand.

Like this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262585/adjusting-single-appendix-title

Try \renewcommand {\thechapter} {}

It also matters how you number the equations etc. inside the appendix.  See also \appendixpage and \appendixpagename which would make the appendix a part rather than a chapter.
